# Colorbar limits not respecting axes clims when displaying an image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Im trying to superimpose a `trimesh`-plot over a image `imshow` using `hold on`. This works fine so far. I'd additionally like to display a `colorbar`, which works too, but unfortunately it does not adjust to the range specified by `caxis`, does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

This is an example output: The colourbar *should* display a range from 1 to `z`, not from 0 to 60. If we remove `imshow` everything works fine.

[image]

Here my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
clc;clf;clear
T = [1,2,3;3,1,4]; % triangulation
X = [0,1,1,0]*300; % grid coordinates
Y = [0,0,1,1]*300;
for z = 2:20;
    clf;
    imshow(imread('board.tif')) % plot image (this is a built in matlab test image)
    hold on
    Z = [1,1,1,z];
    trisurf(T,X,Y,Z)            % superimpose plot 
    colormap hot
    caxis([1,z])
    colorbar
    drawnow
    pause(0.5)
end
```

Comment: What version of MATLAB?

Comment: Oh I forgot to add that, mine is `R2010b`, thanks for asking!

Comment: I cannot test your example since I do not have a board.tif, but have you tried `colorbar('Limits',[1,z]);` instead?

Comment: @Florian This results in an error: `Unknown property 'Limits'.` thanks anyway. The `board.tif` is an example that should be shipped with MATLAB, but you can replace it with any other image (should be at least 300x300, otherwise you can just adjust the `*300` in line 3 and 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in how older versions of MATLAB handled the colorbar (it's not present with HG2). The "correct" behavior would be that if you have *any* objects in the current axes that use scaled values, then the colorbar should respect your `clims`. It seems that MATLAB is using the *first* child in the current axes to determine whether to respect your `clims` or not. `imshow` does not use scaled `CDataMapping` so `colorbar` simply ignores your `clims`.

It looks like you have three options:

1. Use `imagesc` rather than `imshow`

   ```
   clf;
   imagesc(imread('board.tif'));
   axis image
   hold on
   Z = [1,1,1,z];
   trisurf(T,X,Y,Z)            % superimpose plot
   colormap hot
   caxis([1,z])
   drawnow
   colorbar
   drawnow
   pause(0.5)
   ```
2. Call `imshow` *after* you've created your `trisurf` object

   ```
   clf;
   hold on
   Z = [1,1,1,z];
   trisurf(T,X,Y,Z)            % superimpose plot
   colormap hot
   him = imshow(imread('board.tif'));
   caxis([1,z])
   drawnow
   colorbar
   drawnow
   pause(0.5)
   ```
3. Set the [`CDataMapping`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image-properties.html#property_CDataMapping) property of the `image` object to `'scaled'` (will be ignored when displaying the image since it's RGB but it will allow the `colorbar` to function properly)

   ```
   clf;
   him = imshow(imread('board.tif'));
   set(him, 'CDataMapping', 'scaled')
   hold on
   Z = [1,1,1,z];
   trisurf(T,X,Y,Z)            % superimpose plot
   colormap hot
   caxis([1,z])
   drawnow
   colorbar
   drawnow
   pause(0.5)
   ```